# Keep compile definitions when using CMake-built library that has custom target_compile_defintions

Tags: c++, cmake

**Situation:**

I am developing a C++ library managed by CMake that I intend to use in multiple projects. The library has some compile-time configuration that propagates to the defintions of custom "defines" using (e.g.) `target_compile_definitions(my_library PUBLIC "CUSTOM_DEF_OPTION")`. These definitions affect the generated code both in cpp files and headers.

When I am linking this library to another library or executable as part of the same CMake project (using `target_link_libraries(my_executable my_library)`, the PUBLIC defintions are  properly carried over to the compilation of the executable.

**Problem:**

However, this does not work in case the library is used in some external project, managed e.g. by Visual Studio or Eclipse, because the compile definitions are not carried over. This results in discrepancies between the effective header code and already-built library.

Therefore, I need to find a way how to easily apply the PUBLIC compile definitions in the projects using this library.

**Question:**

I was thinking about using CMake's `configure_file(...)` to generate a special header file that would contain the definitions and will be included in the library project instead of using `target_compile_definitions`. It seems I need to manually craft the template file and logic, which duplicates already existing logic for adding target compile defintions.

Is this a correct approach? Is there a way to generate such file automatically? Is there some other more-elegant approach that would work?

Comment: You can generate cmake projects for Visual Studio and you can generate a project via cmake that can easily be imported in Eclipse CDT. Also there's basic cmake support available for Eclipse. If you want to be independent of cmake though I'm afraid there's no alternative to the approach you presented (at least none that I know of). If you're satisfied with providing an installation the user can include into their own cmake project using `find_package` though I recommend taking a look at `install(EXPORT)`

Comment: Thanks. The library is going to be used in projects which do not use CMake, so I cannot use CMake's `install(EXPORT)`.